# my cloud front URL redirect to S3 URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

my cloud front distribution's origin is my S3 bucket . to access a S3 bucket object we put a url in such as like **"cloudfront_domainname/object_name"** it should be show the object if the object is public . but in my case the cloud front URL in the URL bar redirects a S3 URL, the data retrieved from S3 not from cloud front distribution. why it cause ?

Comment: This is *probably* a side effect of the way S3 handles routing traffic to new buckets, for the first few minutes of a bucket's existence.  Is your bucket new?

Comment: yes i tried in a new bucket, how to overcome it? will it get normal after some time

Comment: It should.  You may need to do a [cache invalidation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html) of all objects (`/*`) is it has not started working correctly by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can optionally secure the content in your Amazon S3 bucket so users can access it through CloudFront but cannot access it directly by using Amazon S3 URLs. This prevents anyone from bypassing CloudFront and using the Amazon S3 URL to get content that you want to restrict access to. This step isn't required to use signed URLs, but we recommend it.

To require that users access your content through CloudFront URLs, you perform the following tasks:

- Create a special CloudFront user called an **origin access identity**.
- Give the origin access identity permission to read the objects in your bucket.
- Remove permission for anyone else to use Amazon S3 URLs to read the objects.

Please see documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html)

Comment: it sounds like the problem is that when objects are requested through CloudFront, the browser gets redirected to S3, which is normal for the first few minutes of a bucket's lifecycle, because it takes CloudFront a few minutes to learn that the bucket isn't in us-east-1, which is a built in assumption for all nonexistent buckets.  `*.s3.amazonaws.com` is a DNS wildcard that routes to N. Virgina by default S3 updates with a custom value for each bucket after creation.  When requests arrive at the global endpoint, they're redirected.